# AES encryption - encrypt in Python and decrypt in Java - AEADBadTagException

Tags: python, java, cryptography, aes

I'm currently trying to write some Python Code (with pycryptodome) that encrypts some data which will be decrypted by a Java tool which is not in my control (so, the Java part is fixed).

The process includes RSA encrypting the AES key and adding the AES nonce. I've got all these working, but the AES decryption itself seems to differ. I guess it comes down to some details in the cipher setup but after trying different settings I'm now lost.

The strange part is, I can get the java part to decrypt my python cipher text, but I have to use the `Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE`. Since I can't change the relevant Java code in production, and the Java code uses `Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE`, thats no solution (and it tells me I'm doing something wrong). With `Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE`, I get `javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch`.

I already tried calling `cipher.decrypt` on the Python part (instead of `cipher.encrypt`), but both give me the same result, so somehow Java makes a difference on encrypt / decrypt while Python doesn't... Or it's something completely different.

I've reduced the problem to a minimal example.

Python Code to generate the cipher:

```
import base64
import Crypto.Cipher.AES

aesnonce  = base64.b64decode(b"nsHTfsEFKyVytEk2")
aeskey    = base64.b64decode(b"2hn3S9IsCTut7Hr9SX/7Pg==")
cipher    = Crypto.Cipher.AES.new(aeskey, Crypto.Cipher.AES.MODE_GCM, nonce=aesnonce)

plaintext = b'''Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore.'''
crypted   = cipher.encrypt(plaintext)

print( base64.b64encode(crypted) )
#w0ehWquycruj2KGkRES4M8pc6w4ZM+9HyI+KOXgqybmiYIuU1nsjZJwisZprxx2mczP280ZT5KlCXzSX0h24136m708N8sbX6m+5QlDVa73/r9dRyfSzFeByi51NqVm35wP4oHdxYW5iVx9P8iFFpcYd9c8=
```

And the Java Part

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class MainTest {
    static public void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IOException {
        byte[] aesnonce    = Base64.getDecoder().decode("nsHTfsEFKyVytEk2");
        byte[] aeskeybytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode("2hn3S9IsCTut7Hr9SX/7Pg==");
        byte[] crypted     = Base64.getDecoder().decode("w0ehWquycruj2KGkRES4M8pc6w4ZM+9HyI+KOXgqybmiYIuU1nsjZJwisZprxx2mczP280ZT5KlCXzSX0h24136m708N8sbX6m+5QlDVa73/r9dRyfSzFeByi51NqVm35wP4oHdxYW5iVx9P8iFFpcYd9c8=");
                
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(aeskeybytes, "AES");

        GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, aesnonce);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, gcmParameterSpec);  // Works
//      cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, gcmParameterSpec);  // Error

        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(crypted);
        CipherInputStream cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(inputStream, cipher);
        
        byte[] plaintext = cipherInputStream.readAllBytes();
        System.out.print( new String(plaintext) );
    }
}
```

PS: I'm no Java Guy, and the code is more or less taken from the actual implementation that will be used in production.

PPS: I know that the authentication check is missing. But, since I do not control the protocol, that's what we have to work with.

Comment: Note to my future self and anyone else: Java appends the authentication tag while python gives it separately. Thats probably the issue here, will try and report bag.

Comment: That's correct, but your Python code doesn't return a tag, which is because you are using `encrypt()` instead of [`encrypt_and_digest()`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/modern.html#gcm-mode). The latter returns ciphertext and tag (which can then be concatenated for the Java code).

Comment: @Topaco Yes that was the problem. I've had encrypt_and_digest but didn't know what to do with the digest... It works if i just add it at the end of the cipher. Do you want to formualte an answer?